# How Can I Detect if Currency Accepts Decimal Digits?

Tags: ios, currency-formatting

I am working on formatting user input as currency. I have a very basic view controller that contains two labels and a text field. The scene looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of view controller in Interface Builder]

The leading label is intended to display currency symbols for currencies that contain the symbol before the value. The trailing label is intended to display currency symbols for currencies that contain the symbol after the value. The text field expands and contracts horizontally to fit the entered text so that the trailing currency symbol is always pinned to the entered value. The `text` property of the unused label is set to `nil` so that it appears hidden.

So far, everything works as expected. When setting the scheme's locale to use different currency formats, the labels are populated correctly. I am detecting the position of the currency symbol in the following code:

```swift
internal static var currencySymbolPosition: CurrencySymbolPosition {
    let currencyFormat = CFNumberFormatterGetFormat(CFNumberFormatterCreate(nil, Locale.current as CFLocale, .currencyStyle)) as NSString
    let positiveNumberFormat = currencyFormat.components(separatedBy: ";")[0] as NSString
    let currencySymbolLocation = positiveNumberFormat.range(of: "¤").location
    let position: CurrencySymbolPosition = currencySymbolLocation == 0 ? .start : .end
    return position
}

internal enum CurrencySymbolPosition {
    case start
    case end
}
```

I strip out the currency symbol in the text field, leaving only the value, with any applicable currency decimal separators. That code looks like this:

```swift
internal func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
    guard let currencySymbol = formatter.currencySymbol else { return false }
    guard let decimalSeparator = formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator else { return false }
    guard let groupingSeparator = formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator else { return false }
    guard let newText = (text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) else { return false }
    let symbolsStripped = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: currencySymbol, with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: decimalSeparator, with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: groupingSeparator, with: "")
    guard let integer = Int(symbolsStripped) else { return false }
    let double = Double(integer) / 100
    guard let formatted = formatter.string(from: double as NSNumber) else { return false }
    textField.text = formatted.replacingOccurrences(of: currencySymbol, with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    return false
}
```

The issue that I am running into is that this doesn't work for some currencies. For example, Japanese yen don't use decimals, so `let double = Double(integer) / 100` doesn't work; the result is always `0`. I tried detecting the currency decimal symbol of the yen, but Xcode gives me `.` when I print it out using `print(formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator)`. I had expected an empty string since the `currencyDecimalSeparator` property of `NumberFormatter` is explicitly unwrapped, meaning that it shouldn't be `nil`. I had hoped that I could use the `currencyDecimalSeparator` to determine if I should divide by 100 to get the correct value; a separator would cause division while an empty `currencyDecimalSymbol` would skip the division.

This is what the scene looks like when I set the region to Japan:

[image: Screenshot of iOS Simulator displaying currency format for Japan]

This is what the scene looks like when I set the region to Czech Republic:

[image: Screenshot of iOS Simulator displaying currency format for Czech Republic]

Is there a way to determine which currencies do not use decimals so that I can properly format the text field as the user types?

Comment: Why go through all of the trouble of stripping out all punctuation just to try to put it all back? Just remove the currency symbol and nothing else.

Comment: @rmaddy I am formatting the text field as the use types so that they aren’t required to explicitly enter a decimal. If their locale doesn’t use a decimal separator for currency, then the currency should be formatted from the integer. If their locale does use a decimal separator for currency, then it should be formatted from the double. This way, both types of currency formats are set properly without the user having to type anything other than digits. I hope that clarifies my intentions better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `NumberFormatter` `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` properties to know how many decimal places are used by the locale.

The `maximumFractionDigits` value is most likely what you need. Put 10 to the power of `maximumFractionDigits` and you will have your divisor. Yen should have a value of 0. 10^0 is of course 1. USD and others with a `maximumFractionDigits` of 2 will give you 10^2 which is of course 100.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was able to enter decimals for USD and other currencies with the same format, and I was able to enter only whole numbers for currencies that do not accept decimal formats.